# Ruby : implement an acts_as

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include, rails-engines

I want to implement an acts_as.

This would be something like this :

```
Module Organisable
  def acts_as_organisable
    send :include, InstanceMethods
    has_many ...
    before_destroy ...
    ??
  end
  module InstanceMethods
    def method1
    end    

    def method2
    end
  end
end
```

And it would be used like :

```
def myClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_organisable

end
```

I tried it but it does'nt work. If it's possible i'd like pass parameters too (acts_as_organisable(param) ).

---

This module must be placed in another engine.

For the files organisation i think to :

```
MyEngine
   Models
     MyEngine
        MyEngineClass
     Organisable
        Organisable
```

But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need add your module to lazy load hook. Like this:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  include Organisable
end
```

For more details see [Understanding Ruby and Rails: Lazy load hooks](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/04/understanding-ruby-and-rails-lazy-load-hooks/)